# How to disable listbox horizontal scrolling in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox, matlab-guide, horizontal-scrolling

When a string or sentence becomes too long, the horizontal scrolling of the Matlab GUIDE listbox component is activated. How can I disable this feature and allow the long string or sentence to continue on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the question, so my answer was not correct (but it was accepted).

What you want can be achieved, but it's not documented. Check out [Undocumented features](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-listbox-editbox-scrollbars/), to see more information.

From the link:

Line-wrapping

> By default, line-wrapping is turned on, effectively disabling
>   horizontal scrolling (which is why Matlab set the
>   HorizontalScrollBarPolicy to HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER. However, in
>   some cases it may be more useful to turn line-wrapping off and
>   horizontal scrolling on using the TextArea’s setWrapping() method.
>   Here’s a usage example:
>
> ```
> jViewPort = jScrollPane.getViewport; jEditbox =
> jViewPort.getComponent(0); jEditbox.setWrapping(false);  % do *NOT*
> use set(...)!!! newPolicy =
> jScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
> set(jScrollPane,'HorizontalScrollBarPolicy',newPolicy);
> ```

Also, check this link: [this link](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/smart-listbox-editbox-scrollbars):

<s>If you want it to appear like it's on separate lines, but let Matlab parse it like it's on a single line then you will have to use another editor. I don't think there are any editors with built-in syntax highlighting that supports this, so your best bet is probably something like MS Word with fixed-size font (Courier New or something). A horrible horrible idea, in my opinion, but it's possible.</s>

The "correct" way to do this is to [use `...`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html) to create multi-line strings / assignments etc:

Examples:

```
mystring = ['Accelerating the pace of ' ... 
        'engineering and science'];
```

or with equations:

```
s = 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 ...
      - 1/6 + 1/7 - 1/8 + 1/9;
```